# Mysql get records WHERE MONTHNAME() & YEAR() equals to a value

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to get all 'project' id's from the below table where the conditions is uid='1' and Month='August' and Year='2016'

```
date               |     uid    |     project
-------------------------------------------
Wed, 01 Aug 2016   |     1      |      11
Tue, 15 Aug 2016   |     2      |      11
Mon, 31 Aug 2016   |     1      |      11
Thu, 05 Sep 2016   |     1      |      12
Sat, 10 Sep 2016   |     2      |      12
Mon, 12 Feb 2017   |     3      |      12
Tue, 31 Feb 2017   |     1      |      13
Wed, 31 Mar 2017   |     2      |      13
Fri, 31 Mar 2017   |     3      |      13
Thu, 31 Mar 2017   |     1      |      14
```

Below is the query i use

```
SELECT project FROM logs where uid="1" AND MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%W, %d %M %Y'))="August" AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%W, %d %M %Y'))="2016";
```

But it is returning other month records also. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `AND date like '%Aug%' AND date like '%2016%'` keep it simple.

Comment: if you're not too far into this project, you should consider using mysql's built-in date functions. What you're doing now is a lot of work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just use `like`:

```
SELECT project
FROM logs 
WHERE uid = 1 AND 
      date LIKE '% Aug 2016';
```

Don't store date/time values as strings.  If you do, don't call them "date", call them something like "datestr" to prevent unexpected errors.  But if it a string, you can treat it like a string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This query also return Aug 2017 records.

Comment: @Thowzif . . . How would it do that?  The `like` pattern *explicitly* has 2016.  Do you have records that have different date formats?

Comment: Thanks for your query. I have figured it out. It was a single \" character that was making that result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT project 
FROM logs 
WHERE uid= 1
AND MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%W, %d %M %Y'))= 'August' 
AND YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(date,'%W, %d %M %Y'))= 2016
;
```

Comment: Im failing to see the difference betweeen your query to mine. Can you explain.

Comment: @Thowzif you are mention uid and year part as string use as integer.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I've used the query suggested by Gordon Linoff. Thnaks for your efforts.